# Denying Request in Xmpp - Remove Entry from roster

Tags: android, xmpp

In XMPP when I send a friend request to other user, if other wants to deny it then, the entry from the roster should be removed, but I am not able to remove the entry from user. It is giving me force close ( with null pointer exception)

Here is my deny button code

```
btn_Deny = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_manageNotification_DENY);
        btn_Deny.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Presence unsubscribe = new Presence(Presence.Type.unsubscribed);
                unsubscribe.setTo(id);              
                connection.sendPacket(unsubscribe);

                /*String message = mXmconn.removeFriend(subID, CMMStaticVariable.CommonConnection);
                System.out.println(message);*/

                Intent returnBack = new Intent(ManageNotification.this, UserMenuActivity.class);
                startActivity(returnBack);
                finish();               
            }
        });     
    }
```

Remove Friend

```
public String removeFriend(String jid, XMPPConnection connection){
        roster = connection.getRoster();
        String message = "";
        try {
            RosterEntry rosterEntry = roster.getEntry("chamak@abec.info.com");
            System.out.println("rosterEntryy"+rosterEntry.toString());

            roster.removeEntry(rosterEntry);
            message = "You have denied the friend request";
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            message = "Exception";
        }
        return message;
    }
```

It is giving null pointer at rosterEntry = null;

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

XMPP-CORE defines that the server must delete the roster item from the user's roster upon rejection of the subscription request. Therefore, the item not even supposed to be there when you try to request it.

From the specification:

> Note: If the contact's server previously added the user to the contact's roster for tracking purposes, it MUST remove the relevant item at this time.

You can read more [here](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#int-sub-alt).

Comment: But the roster item with none status is not deleting at all, rather it is giving me null pointer exception at RosterEntry.

Thanks